# Jenkins job hangs on "git push origin branch" due to authentification

Tags: git, jenkins

I try to do the folowing in jenkins job shell command:

checked out develop branch, did some changes, committed and pushed to origin branch as follow:

```
1. check out the develop branch:
git remote add origin http://name@url/project
git checkout develop
2. make some changes
3. commit changes
git commit -a -m "committed"
4. push to origin 
git push origin develop
```

jenkins job hung up on the last step. see the screenshot

[image]

what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the git URL you provided I see your not using SSH URL, when your trying to push it is probably expecting the password. I would trying following

1. Try to do same steps from terminal after logging into Jenkins
   server, see whether you face same error
2. Configure your password in jenkins job and use it part of your shell script like below

   expect -c 'spawn sudo git push origin develop; expect -ex {assword:}; send -- '$password'\n; expect eof exit'

Comment: i have switched to ssh and did the same steps and it print the following error:** + git push origin develop
Password authentication
Password authentication
Password authentication
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (password,keyboard-interactive,publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

Comment: Apparently, your system tries to authenticate via a password, which is wrong. Alternatively, also other authentification schemes are allowed from your server, but could not be used. Therefore, could you please test what item 1 of @Mowgli does?