# Jenkins job hangs while pushing commits to Git repo

Tags: git, jenkins, push

I'm using Jenkins 2.74.
I'm trying to push commits to the Git repo after doing changes.

This is my pipeline code:

```
stage('push to git') {
    steps{
        bat returnStdout: true, script: '"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\git.exe"  add -A'
        bat returnStdout: true, script: '"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\git.exe"  commit -m "upadte yaml"'
        bat returnStdout: true, script: '"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\git.exe" push -u origin master'
    }
}
```

But, for some reason, the job cannot be completed and it's stuck like this:

[image]

I tried it on my machine, using windows cmd, and it works.
But not on Jenkins.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks to me that it hangs on the `git push ...` part. As this uses the network, I suspect some proxy or firewall issues

Comment: try to push from the machine itself , to make sure your credentials are OK.

Comment: i tried and it's work from the machine...

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/q/37350532/2745495?

Comment: Having the same problem attempting to push tags. I'm using git 2.13 and Jenkins ver. 2.73. Checkout works fine with the git client plugin, but the push hangs. I've tried creating GIT_SSH and SSH_ASKPASS environment variables with no luck. Pushing from the command line works fine.

Comment: I just tested with https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.14.2.windows.2/MinGit-2.14.2.2-64-bit.zip and it appears to resolve the issue. (latest windows version of git)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when process git clone command by **windows shell/bat** in jenkins. This is my solution:

Register key in know_host file
Jenkins will not auto import new key of known host to your know_host file. You can do it manually by following these steps:

1. Login to your local account in windows
2. SSH this git remote path directly ssh  -p
   , type yes to register the key enter image description here
3. Copy the registered key form local account know_host (C:\Users\something\.ssh)
   at the bottom omf the file you will see something like:

> [gerrit.cartography.com]:29168,[10.25.174.78]:29168 ssh-rsa
>   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAASSSSAQABAAAAgQDPHbDKCHL3oPbzDn3qaVZR8S1EZx/rb500Th/fjQYg5jrJ7PBMVVUyNTpJ2moje5hLYjNsVtXtcoNEZjImGul2dl3f+eHrCB27X5198jr8Wj66I/xsQCLEngd7l3velsdfgd3432fsdDiFaE9INjDjgngfNzlFA+CYpFsnaorZ6XSPQ==

4. paste to end of 'system' `know_hosts` file in

   - C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.ssh
   - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\.ssh

I think you will resolve your problem now ! Enjoy it!

Comment: This really helped me. I had a Jenkins instance running under the system account, and that account had never logged in to github. So I actually just had to do that manually to get the `known_hosts` resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the same problem.

Jenkins job stuck forever after executing git push command. But, same command works fine in Windows cmd.

I tried to execute git clone command as follows,

```
http://{GIT_ID}:{GIT_PASSWORD}@{REPOSITORY}.git
```

and added modifications, committed and pushed.

**Then it was finished successfully**.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem (pushing a tag) with git for windows version 2.13.0. Updating to 2.14.2 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, you need to check some details:

1. ensure your Jenkins user on the Jenkins server know your git repository and the configurations
2. Do the "Checkout" with Jenkins "git" plugin and use the SSH option (after you share the ssh keys)

That's it, i think.